# Save image to a new directory(app_name)

Tags: java, android

The following code is able to save images in pictures directory, but I'm not able to find the perfect way to save image files to the desired app directory using URI.

Edit: The perfect way to store image files to a new directory which can be accessed by other apps is the requirement

**SaveActivity.java**

```
 final MediaManager mediaManager = new MediaManager(this); 
    Uri imageURI = mediaManager.GetImageUri(); 
    final ImageView imageHolder = findViewById(R.id.imageHolder);
    Glide.with(this).load(imageURI).into(imageHolder);
    final String filename = mediaManager.getFileName(imageURI); 
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override public void onClick(View v) {
                            imageHolder.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                            Bitmap bitmap = imageHolder.getDrawingCache();
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, filename, "description");
                        }
                    });
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
ImageButton btImgSettings = findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto);
    btnPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
            });
    }
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                switch (requestCode){
                    case 1: if (uri != null) {
                            String stringUri = uri.toString();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SaveActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("imageId", stringUri);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                    default:
                        break;
                        }
             }
   }
```

**MediaManager**

```
public class MediaManager {
    Activity activity;
    public MediaManager(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    public Uri GetImageUri() {
        Uri imageURI = null;
        Bundle bundle = activity.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String imageId = bundle.getString("imageId");
            imageURI = Uri.parse(imageId);
        }
        return imageURI;
    }
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You need to explain what you want to happen, and what is actually happening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The above snippet is able to save an image that is present in image holder to the documents directory. My requirement is to create a separate directory to store all media files in the root. where the gallery and other apps can access my folder.

Comment: `intent.putExtra("imageId", stringUri);`. We cannot see how you use that uri in the next activity. You showed us only that you took a name from it. But what it has to do with the bitmap you save is a mistery.

Comment: thanks for your response @blackapps, I have created a sperate class called MediaManager which is retrieving the URI and returning to  imageURI of SaveActivity.java and I'm converting the URI to bitmap to store it in documents and the code is working fine. my ultimate target is to create a separate directory in root folder and save media files over there.

Comment: `I'm converting the URI to bitmap ` What i said was that we do not see that code as the bitmap comes from a holder. Not from that uri.

Comment: `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver()....` Are you telling us that that line stores a bitmap in the Documents directory? Hard to believe.

Comment: @blackapps yes, according to the android file manager info it is said the directory is in the document, but I found the image under pictures directory of internal storage. I want to store the media file in the right way under the name of my application, thank you.

Comment: We still dont see code that uses the obtained uri.

Comment: `it is said the directory is in the document, ...`??? Now what would that be?

Comment: @blackapps thank you for spotting the missing line in my submission. I have edited the post. I hope you the missing piece.

Comment: `According to file manager info its present in documents but the real path is in pictures` Sorry, but i dont see anything with documents in that picture.

Comment: @blackapps I have added an image link at the end. thank you :)

Comment: Yes. I'm referring exactly to that link. I quoted it!  But as said: i dont see a file in something like documents.

Comment: @blackapps document/image:37 isn't that root of the file? sorry if I had miss understood

Comment: Please next time only post a picture of the emulator. What you see has nothing to do with a document folder or a storage location.  It only tells that the image is a document. Only part of the uri is shown. Compare with imageUri.toString(). Pretty bad app to show it that way.

Comment: Thanks for making me understand the file info part. As of now on Btsave click, the image present in imageholder should be saved in a separate directory(my app name) and I will make sure next time to send a screenshot of emulator alone thank you:)

Comment: Please tell full path of your wanted directory. It is pretty unclear now. If i look at the subject of your post its pretty strange that you first put a selected file in an image holder, then try to get a bitmap of it and then save the bitmap. Why all this fuss if all you want is copy a file?

Comment: @blackapps as of now I haven't made changes to the image holder, so it may feel like I'm just making a copy of the original image, but it isn't and the root directory( I'm asking you what's the right way to store media files which are accessible to the user under my app name) thank you :)

Comment: You should decide where you wanna copy those files to. Dont ask me. Know what you want. Further you are talking about media files but only images can be stored in the holder and converted to bitmap. Not audio or video files. Why is it that i still dont know what you exactly want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the file to your directory and then use.

```
Bitmap image= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());

File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "YourDirectory");

        if (!root.exists()) root.mkdirs();

        String file = root.toString() + File.separator + "FileName" + ".jpg";

        try {
            FileOutputStream fOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fOutputStream);

            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);

            fOutputStream.flush();
            fOutputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{file}, null, null);
        //This line notifies the system that an image was added and to show it in the gallery.
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: Thanks @Vishnu, the above snippet that you shared is working fine.

Comment: @Viswajith Happy to hear that. Please mark it as the accepted answer (Green Tick Mark). Thank you